# How do dilated 1d Convolution layers work?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to replicate a Variational Autoencoder design for speech reconstruction to use it on other types of sound data within eco-acoustics, but I ran into an issue when implementing the architecture from scratch.

In the original paper, the authors work with the Short-Time Fourier Transform to get magnitude and phase spectrograms which are then reconstructed with a VAE. They use a complicated design of blocks of layers (see photo below). One of the blocks is a so-called temporal block. In the methods of the paper, the authors describe this block as follows:

> "Temporal Block consisting of 4 one-dimensional dilated CLs applied along the time frame axis. The kernel size is 3 with dilations of 1, 2, 4, and 8 for the different layers. This block is used to capture the temporal dynamic of the latent variables."

I don't really understand what they mean by this and was hoping someone could help me understand it .

### Additional Information

- The tensors are organised as follows tensor.shape(c,d,N: (channel, d =vector length for frame n, N = number of Frames); but in effect, d is the height, and N is the width.
- For most of the model, the width/temporal dimension/number of frames stays the same, resulting in a latent space that is of shape 1,32,N.
- The temporal block will capture the relationship on the temporal axis, and the shape after the temporal block must be (1,65,N) (see image 2: the vertical axes on the encoder and decoder shows the dimension).
- There are different blocks in the model: DB is a dense block (multiple convolutions + output concat), TD is a transition down (reduces dimensionality across the y/frequency axis), TU is a transition up (same as TD but reversed), FC is fully connected, TE is a transition expand (expands channels).
- The paper can be found here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.03269

[image: Model Overview]

[image: Architecture Overview]

```
# Temporal Block

class TemporalBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, dilation_rates):
        super(TemporalBlock, self).__init__()
        self.conv_layers = nn.ModuleList()
        
        for dilation_rate in dilation_rates:
            padding = (kernel_size - 1) * dilation_rate
            self.conv_layers.append(
                nn.Conv1d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size,
                          padding=padding, dilation=dilation_rate)
            )
            in_channels = out_channels  # Update input channel size for next layer
            
        self.padding = padding
        
    def forward(self, x):
        for conv in self.conv_layers:
            x = conv(x)
            # Remove extra padded values to preserve original temporal length
            x = x[:, :, :-self.padding]
        return x

# Initialize block
temporal_block = TemporalBlock(in_channels=32, out_channels=65, kernel_size=3, dilation_rates=[1, 2, 4, 8])
temporal_block(mu).shape
```

This is my current code for the temporal block, but its not correct, as the output dimensions are (1,65,26), which cannot be right.